# Monitoring outgoing internet traffic

Tags: c#, .net, networking, network-programming

Is there a way to monitoring internet traffic programatically? I would like to log the pages  users are visiting on the Internet. Can this be achieved with .NET code, is there a 3rd party .NET component that could be used to retrieved data.

Information about Internet traffic must be stored to a database so I cannot use a plugin or something for IE. We are also looking to include this code into our existing product so we cannot use a 3rd party product that cannot be redistributed.

It would be cool if this thing could monitor traffic for all browsers but monitoring IE traffic might also be sufficient.

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us what your product is supposed to do. Also is it intended for a singe PC or as a network based solution that runs on a server?

Answer (score 6):

Setting up a sniffer is doable via the [WinPCap](https://www.winpcap.org/) library, which has several projects wrapping it to .NET:

- [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20190907100347/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/dotnetnomad/archive/2008/01/31/119140.aspx)
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/dotnetwinpcap.aspx
- http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2006/02/sharppcap-net-winpcap-wrapper.html

and probably some others as well, just a matter of Googling.

Comment: WinPCap rules for passive monitoring. The most simple thing to do (without getting into other 3rd parties besides winpcap) - is to bypass wpcap.dll and use packet.dll directly. It is a DLL with low-level API functions that are very easy to wrap in .NET

Comment: Huh it seems this WInPCap might do it, however it seem to be too complicated to use, and it is open source solution and that might be a problem because our product is not.

Comment: The license allows it:

Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:

Read conditions at http://www.winpcap.org/misc/copyright.htm

Comment: @Andrey There's no need to write a WinPcap wrapper for C# as they already exist. That's the function of SharpPcap and Pcap.Net. And yes, both projects are open source licensed.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to build some software that acts as a proxy.  You should start by looking at programs like "Fiddler" to understand the concepts and what you need to implement.

If you want my profesional opionon you should go to Server Fault and ask for opionons for low cost internet proxy solution.  Writing this thing yourself while challenging and fun will not make good business sense.

Comment: Well I do not see how we could redistribute a low cost internet server proxy?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to monitor all traffic from everyone on your network consider a product like Microsoft's [Internet Security and Acceleration (ISA) Server](http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/edgesecurity/isaserver/en/us/overview.aspx)

While this is probably overkill for what you want, the point is that you need a way to have all traffic go through a single point (a proxy server) where the traffic can be logged. Since all traffic goes through this one point, users can't avoid detection by using an alternate browser etc.

Comment: Yup, this is great BUT we cannot redistribute ISA with our product :(

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [Pcap.Net](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com) to easily use WinPcap in .NET.
It is a wrapper for WinPcap written in C++/CLI and C# and includes a packet interpretation and creation framework.

Answer (score 0):

Like [JD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903612/monitoring-outgoing-internet-traffic/903619#903619) already mentioned you should take a look into [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). With this proxy you are able to monitor all the web traffic (if your browser is configured to use fiddler as proxy).

If you don't want fiddler as a standalone application and need its functionality within your own app, you should take a look into [FiddlerCore](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore). It is a .Net assembly which encapsulates the core functionality of Fiddler.

If you need a more raw way to sniff into the data (maybe you don't want to [or can't] configure the proxy of the client) the answer from [Vinko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903612/monitoring-outgoing-internet-traffic/903617#903617) will help you further.