# How to Check Single URL WebTraffic in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, url, web, traffic

I am creating a Windows Form C# application. in which I need to trace the Single URL web traffic, like FireBug of Mozilla, Charles, Fiddler etc. But I don't want to use its features, because of software dependency.

I found this ([Monitoring outgoing internet traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903612/monitoring-outgoing-internet-traffic/903617#903617)) also, but most of solutions are using API. So not suitable for me.

So can any one please let me know, how can I create such application, where I can track single URL web Traffic? in C# only. No API please

Comment: Its Using Same Fiddler API. So can not use. Thanks Anyway

Comment: You don't want to use anything and want a solution. How for example?

Comment: So You mean to say its not possible, without any API? i searched google also and found an idea here, but don't know how it works http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyb3xww8.aspx

Comment: First, what do you understand from API? win32 calls? external .NET library?  COM components?

Comment: If i use FiddlerCore then i need to install Fiddler in each system, with my application? I am new in C#, so no idea, what you want to ask.

Comment: No, it is just a single .DLL. No Fiddler installation required.

Comment: Oh great. Where can i get this DLL anyway? :) Feeling happy by your response now.

Comment: Don't be so lazy and google :)

Comment: :) I got it. http://fiddlerbook.com/Fiddler/Core/.. Please make your comment as Answer with this link. So that i will make your response as Answer. http://fiddlerbook.com/Fiddler/Core/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using fiddler core api, you could do this,

[Fiddler Core](http://fiddlerbook.com/Fiddler/Core/)

In Code,

If its a windows application, On

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += Fiddler_AfterSessionComplete;
            Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(0, Fiddler.FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default);

         }

    private void Fiddler_AfterSessionComplete(Fiddler.Session osession)
        {
            listWatch.Invoke(new UpdateUI(() =>
            {

               if(osession.fullUrl == "Your Url")
                {
                 //bind data
                }

           }));


        }
```

Comment: I can trace the URLs but when I try to load a file (suppose http://url.com/path/xmlfilename.xml) then Its blocking Internet by making checkbox tick in Internet Explorer Proxy Setting. So please suggest what to do now?